# android sqlite syntax error near "to"

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax

So i get this exception:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax
>   error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE betalingen (_id
>   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,id TEXT,amount TEXT,to TEXT,from TEXT,context TEXT
>   )

In my sqlite class I make the text to make the db like this:

```
**public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "betalingen.db";
private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_TO + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_FROM + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_CONTEXT + TEXT_TYPE +
                " )";**
```

And here is my Feedentry class:

```
public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "betalingen";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String COLUMN_TO = "to";
    public static final String COLUMN_FROM = "from";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTEXT = "context";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE = null;

}
```

I can't seem to get the mistake I made. I hope someone will see it :D!

Answer (score 5):

`to` is a keyword. You can't have `to` as a field name in SQlite. `from` is also a keyword, you shouldn't use that as well.

Here's a complete list of keywords in SQlite: https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 1):

`to` is a keyword so it cannot be used without quoting.

Try:

```
public static final String COLUMN_TO = "\"to\"";
```

or change column name.